# activemq --extdir option doesn't seem to work

Tags: activemq-classic

I am starting an active mq broker using my own config file:

```
./apache-activemq-5.6.0/bin/activemq console xbean:custom-broker.xml
```

The broker is using some classes I have defined which reside in a jar. For a while now I was just sticking the jar in the activemq lib folder, and everything worked fine.
However I would now like for active mq to pick up the jar from a different folder, something which the `--extdir` option claims to be capable of doing. However I can't get it to work.
I am executing the command:

```
./apache-activemq-5.6.0/bin/activemq console xbean:custom-broker.xml --extdir ../mylib/
```

where the jar in question is located in mylib, and am getting ClassNotFoundException every time.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you find --extdir option?
You may need to point jvm to external libs directory instead.

Comment: @GermannArlington if you type activemq -? you will see the extdir option listed. How can I point jvm to external libs directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. --extdir does work as expected, turns out someone changed the name of one of the packages by like 1 character, and this is why activemq couldnt find the class in question in the jar :P.
Also worth noting that if you want to add multiple folders to active mq's classpath, then you need to repeat --extdir multiple times, as in "--extdir foldr1 --extdir foldr2" as documented here:

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Is-there-anyway-to-get-activeMQ-to-pick-up-a-jar-at-runtime-other-than-adding-it-to-the-activemqinst-td4654121.html#a4654190